How to calculate the RL-type CFD of $e^{-t}$: $^{RL}_0T_{\alpha}(t) = (1-\alpha)(e^{-t}) - \alpha t^{1-\alpha} e^{-t}$ for $t \in (-\infty, 0]$?
I'm trying to implement a paper I've found on the open-access journal AI Open: Enhancing neural network classification using fractional-order activation functions.
They propose activation functions based on the concept of "fractional-order derivatives" which is completely new to me.
Following their explanation for calculating the RL-type Conformable Fractional Derivative of $e^{-t}$, it would be defined as:
$$
^{RL}_0T_{\alpha}(t)
=
(1-\alpha)(e^{-t}) - \alpha t^{1-\alpha} e^{-t}
$$
The issue comes is that it's only defined for $t \in [0, \infty)$, but that's so limiting within neural networks as activation functions are usually defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.
They even show in Fig. 2 the function plotted over the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, which really confused me, how did they do so? are they using a formula different from the one they presented on the paper? are they allowed to do so? what am I missing.
Fig. 2: shows the generalized exponential function of order α, ranging in (0,1].
Over the positive domain I was able to plot the following:
A plot of the presented formula using my implementation in Python and NumPy.
This $^{RL}_0T_{\alpha}(t)$ function is used later to define the modified sigmoid function $^{RL}F\sigma(t)$ (13):
$$
^{RL}\mathrm{F}\sigma(t)
=
\frac{1}{1+^{RL}_0T_{\alpha}(t)}
$$
Fig. 3: Characteristics of new fractional activation functions.
And sigmoid is only useful when defined on $\mathbb{R}$.
The problem can be narrowed down specifically to not being able to calculate $t^{1-\alpha}$ for $t \in (-\infty, 0]$ within $\mathbb{R}$.
AI (MS Copilot) has suggested to solve it within $\mathbb{C}$, but that won't do as neural networks activation functions have to be in $\mathbb{R}$ as far as I know.
Is there a way to calculate $t^{1-\alpha}$ for $t \in (-\infty, 0]$? or maybe there's a different formula for the RL-type CFD $^{RL}_0T_{\alpha}(t)$ over negative values?
I couldn't embed images in this post (due to insufficient reputation on the platform). So had to link them instead.
Thanks for help, it's very appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hey @Community bot. I think my post is limited to a specific problem, isn't it? If it's not clear please I want a human to verify.
